# How to hide the items in popup menu in system tray of the application?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I would like to hide update or hide certain popup menu items in the taskbar (system tray) of my application only. How do i do that?

Comment: i meant of my application of course. Perhaps there is some property that can be set off.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Delphi TTrayIcon component for this then the answer lies in its `PopupMenu` property.

Through this property you can Access to TTrayIcon underlying PopupMenu at runtime in order to do necessary changes as you would do to any popup menu.

Or you could even assign your own PopupMenu to act as TTrayIcon PopupMenu. With this approach you can design several different PopupMenu-es at design time and then simply chose appropriate PopupMenu to be used at certain time of your Application execution.